# C# wpf, Is it bad to use both the wpf and gdi assemblies?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a wpf application and some parts of my code need to use a integer rectangle structure which is available from System.Drawing.Rectangle while I am using the double type System.Windows.Rect for actual drawings.
Is this a bad idea to reference both the GDI+ and WPF assemblies?
Should I just implement my own integer rect structure?

Comment: Is an integer rectangle structure the *only* thing you need? If so, then heavens no, don't import the GDI+ assemblies just for that. If you actually need the GDI+ drawing functions, though, then there's no problem using them together.

Comment: Thanks, yes, the integer rectangle struct is all I need from GDI+ but why is it a bad idea? Will it slow down the loading of the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `System.Drawing.Rectangle`. Use [`System.Windows.Int32Rect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.int32rect(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know of this one!